# What is target="_new"? validator giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

What is `target="_new"`? Validator is raising an error..

How do you do this with jquery because Validator is raising an error.

On the same page, I have  `target="_new"` and  `target="_blank"`.  `target="_new"` is in that form code which i received from email newsletter company.

I'm using this for `target="_blank"`

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href^=http]').click( function() {
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

What should i do for  `target="_new"`

**Update:**  **1 min Ago**

upon clicking on submit button i want to open a page in new window to pass validation how to do this in jquery as i'm doing for other external link.

update:

this is code

```
<form method="post" class="form-wrapper" action="http://sitename.com/form.php">
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no such thing as `target="_new"`. Using this will simply open the link in a new window *called* "_new". You might notice that clicking on a link with target="_new" will open a new window (or tab) but then a second link will open in the *same* window (or tab), rather than opening a second one as you'd probably expect.

Personally, I don't think you should be specifying `target="_blank"` at all - let the user choose.

Answer (score 3):

target="_blank" is invalid in XHTML (actually, the entire target attribute is invalid).  If you want a link to open in a new window (usually a bad idea, in my opinion) and validation is important to you, the only way to do it is with javascript (like you did).

Answer (score 0):

This is an attribute for a(anchor) tag, which let you open the page on the same window or in a new window.